# Laravel 5.1 AuthController Validate and Create

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am having trouble in laravel 5.1 registration in the AuthController the validate and create method. I make may login and register forms in one page so I added **register-** on the inputs of the registration form (ex. **register-email** for the email address in the registration form). So my validate method in the AuthController is this:

App\Auth\Http\Controllers\Auth

```
/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'last-name'                 => 'required|between:2,35',
        'first-name'                => 'required|between:2,35',
        'register-email'            => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'register-password'         => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
        'register-confirm-password' => 'same:register-password'
    ]);
}
```

The **last-name**, **first-name**, **register-email**, **etc** is a html inputs right? So I think this is right?
and then this is the create method:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'last-name'   => $data['last-name'],
        'first-name'  => $data['first-name'],
        'email'       => $data['register-email'],
        'password'    => bcrypt($data['register-password'])
    ]);
}
```

The keys in the create method is the database table right? and the value is the html input name/id? I am getting Unknown column error of `register-email` why is that? I know I don't have **register-email** column in the database but, in the create method I specify the `email` column in the database and not **register-column** which is the html input name of my registration form. Please help.

BTW this is my database migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('last-name');
        $table->string('first-name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: you dont need to add register on the inputs of the registration form ,just use the normal one, just use email & password in name attribute in both form

Comment: Name of email and password inputs is also used in login form in the same page as the registration form. I think it is not a good idea?

Comment: it's not a problem, but if you want to identify them differently then use different id, but you can use same name, no problem in that

Comment: When I put something in the login form email input and nothing in the registration email input, and I click the register submit button I think it is going to get the email data in the login form because they have the same input ID which is not a good practice in HTML Structure also?

Comment: your login form & registration form are different,so when you give input in login form and click submit button of registration button, validation failed in registration form because its have no input, so one form doesn't get another forms data